# converting unix process to regular process in java

Tags: java, matlab, process

I'm using `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` in Matlab to build and start a process. This process gets passed to a Java class that reads data from the process.

In Matlab I have this:

```
        temp_process_builder = java.lang.ProcessBuilder(cmd_array);

        %Starting the process
        %--------------------------------------------------
        obj.j_process       = temp_process_builder.start();
        obj.j_error_stream  = obj.j_process.getErrorStream;
        obj.j_input_stream  = obj.j_process.getInputStream;
        obj.j_output_stream = obj.j_process.getOutputStream;
```

On Windows, the classes are:

- `java.lang.ProcessImpl` for the process
- `java.io.FileInputStream` for error
- `java.io.BufferedInputStream` for the input
- `java.io.BufferedOutputStream` for the output

  The Java constructor I'm calling is:

  ```
  public NEURON_reader(BufferedInputStream pin, FileInputStream perr, Process p) {
     this.p    = p;
     this.perr = perr;
     this.pin  = pin;
  }
  ```

Later calls are made to `read()` and `available()` methods of `perr` and `pin`.

I recently tried running the code using a Mac machine, but now the classes are:

- `java.lang.UNIXProcess` for the process
- `java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream` for the error and input
- `java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeOutputStream` for the output

Passing these variables to my Java code results in an error due to the mismatch in data types => "No constructor 'NEURON_reader' with matching
signature found."

My question is, is it possible to easily convert the unix process values to what I'm seeing on Windows. Alternatively, is there some easy way of writing a generic wrapper that behind the scenes uses one or the other? Put simply, what's the best way of making my old code run on Macs?

On a final note, I only use the input and error streams in Java, whereas I write to the output stream in Matlab. Not sure if that helps ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program to the *interfaces* instead of the concrete types. Instead of `java.lang.ProcessImpl` use the abstract class ("interface") [`java.lang.Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). And instead of `BufferedInputStream` and `FileInputStream` use the `InputStream` interface.

```
public NEURON_reader(InputStream pin, InputStream perr, Process p) {
```

Note that in Java while the implementations returned on various platforms may differ, the **documented** public interfaces remain the same.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll give it a try later today. Thanks.